# Counting Frequencies of Sequences

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Suppose there are two students - each student takes an exam multiple times (e.g.result_id = 1 is the first exam, result_id = 2 is the second exam, etc.). The student can either "pass" (1) or "fail" (0).

The data looks something like this:

```
library(data.table)

my_data = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), results = c(0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0), result_id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))

my_data = setDT(my_data)

  id results result_id
 1:  1       0         1
 2:  1       1         2
 3:  1       0         3
 4:  1       1         4
 5:  1       0         5
 6:  1       0         6
 7:  2       1         1
 8:  2       1         2
 9:  2       1         3
10:  2       0         4
11:  2       1         5
12:  2       1         6
13:  2       0         7
14:  2       1         8
15:  2       0         9
```

**I am interested in counting the number of times that a student passes an exam, given that the student passed the previous two exams.**

I tried to do this with the following code:

```
my_data$current_exam = shift(my_data$results, 0)
my_data$prev_exam = shift(my_data$results, 1)
my_data$prev_2_exam = shift(my_data$results, 2)

# Count the number of exam results for each record
out <- my_data[!is.na(prev_exam), .(tally = .N), by = .(id, current_exam, prev_exam, prev_2_exam)]

out = na.omit(out)
```

My code produces the following results:

```
> out
   id current_exam prev_exam prev_2_exam tally
1:  1            0         1           0     2
2:  1            1         0           1     1
3:  1            0         0           1     1
4:  2            1         0           0     1
5:  2            1         1           0     2
6:  2            1         1           1     1
7:  2            0         1           1     2
8:  2            1         0           1     2
9:  2            0         1           0     1
```

**However, I do not think that my code is correct.**

For example, with Student_ID = 2 :

- My code says that  "Current_Exam = 1, Prev_Exam = 1, Prev_2_Exam = 0" happens 1 time, but looking at the actual data - this does not happen at all

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and how I can correct this?

Note: I think that this should be the expected output:

```
> expected_output
   id current_exam prev_exam prev_2_exam tally
1:  1            0         1           0     2
2:  1            1         0           1     1
3:  1            0         0           1     1
4:  2            1         0           0     1
5:  2            1         1           0     1
6:  2            1         1           1     1
7:  2            0         1           1     2
8:  2            1         0           1     2
9:  2            0         1           0     0
```

Comment: Why the first id has a tally value of "2"? i expct 0 or i didnt understand.

Comment: @ Ric : For student_1 : (0,1,0,1,0,0) ... I can see: **0,1,0**,1,0,0 and 0,1,**0,1,0**,0

Comment: So the output should be student_1: 0 (doesn't happen at all), student_2: 1 (only happens one time)? Would still be eager to see the expected output as I am afraid I don't understand.

Comment: @ harre: I added the expected output, I was still revising it - thank you so much!

Comment: how is `0,1,0` a count? ie the question states to count the number of times the student passes an exam given that he/she passed the previous two exams. ie the current must be pass ie 1. Then the two previous exams must also be 1. Unless you meant to state- Count how many times the student*TAKES* an exam given that he passed *ANY* of the previous two exams. In this case, we can take  different approaches as long as the previous two exams are not `0, 0`\

Answer (score 2):

You did not consider that you can not shift the results over id without placing `NA`.

```
. <- my_data[order(my_data$id, my_data$result_id),] #sort if needed
.$p1 <- ave(.$results, .$id, FUN = \(x) c(NA, x[-length(x)]))
.$p2 <- ave(.$p1, .$id, FUN = \(x) c(NA, x[-length(x)]))
aggregate(list(tally=.$p1), .[c("id","results", "p1", "p2")], length)
#  id results p1 p2 tally
#1  1       0  1  0     2
#2  2       0  1  0     1
#3  2       1  1  0     1
#4  1       0  0  1     1
#5  1       1  0  1     1
#6  2       1  0  1     2
#7  2       0  1  1     2
#8  2       1  1  1     1

.
#   id results result_id p1 p2
#1   1       0         1 NA NA
#2   1       1         2  0 NA
#3   1       0         3  1  0
#4   1       1         4  0  1
#5   1       0         5  1  0
#6   1       0         6  0  1
#7   2       1         1 NA NA
#8   2       1         2  1 NA
#9   2       1         3  1  1
#10  2       0         4  1  1
#11  2       1         5  0  1
#12  2       1         6  1  0
#13  2       0         7  1  1
#14  2       1         8  0  1
#15  2       0         9  1  0
```

An option would be to use `filter` to indicate those which had passed 3 times in a row.

```
cbind(., n=ave(.$results, .$id, FUN = \(x) filter(x, c(1,1,1), sides=1)))
#   id results result_id  n
#1   1       0         1 NA
#2   1       1         2 NA
#3   1       0         3  1
#4   1       1         4  2
#5   1       0         5  1
#6   1       0         6  1
#7   2       1         1 NA
#8   2       1         2 NA
#9   2       1         3  3
#10  2       0         4  2
#11  2       1         5  2
#12  2       1         6  2
#13  2       0         7  2
#14  2       1         8  2
#15  2       0         9  1
```

If olny *the number of times that a student passes an exam, given that the student passed the previous two exams*:

```
sum(ave(.$results, .$id, FUN = \(x) filter(x, c(1,1,1))==3), na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 1

sum(ave(.$results, .$id, FUN = \(x)
    x==1 & c(x[-1], 0) == 1 & c(x[-1:-2], 0, 0) == 1))
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using dplyr. It uses the lag function to look back 1 and 2 results. If the sum together with the current result is 3, then the condition is met. In the example you provided, the condition is only met once

```
my_data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(threex = ifelse(results + lag(results,1) + lag(results, 2) == 3, 1, 0)) %>%
    filter(!is.na(threex))

      id results result_id threex
   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1       0         3      0
 2     1       1         4      0
 3     1       0         5      0
 4     1       0         6      0
 5     2       1         3      1
 6     2       0         4      0
 7     2       1         5      0
 8     2       1         6      0
 9     2       0         7      0
10     2       1         8      0
11     2       0         9      0
```

If you then just want to capture the cases when the condition is met, add a filter.

```
my_data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(threex = ifelse(results + lag(results,1) + lag(results, 2) == 3, 1, 0)) %>%
    filter(threex == 1)

     id results result_id threex
  <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1     2       1         3      1
```

If you are looking to understand how many times the condition is met per id, you can do this.

```
my_data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(threex = ifelse(results + lag(results,1) + lag(results, 2) == 3, 1, 0)) %>%
    filter(threex == 1) %>%
    select(id) %>%
    summarize(count = n())

    id count
  <dbl> <int>
1     2     1
```

Comment: @ Stomper: thank you so much for your answer! How can I use your code to find out the "number of times" in which this happens?

Comment: I assume you mean number of times per id. See my updated answer. It shows one instance for id #2.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to count events that happen in series, `cumsum()` comes in quite handy. As opposed to creating multiple lagged variables, this scales well to counts across a larger number of events:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- my_data |> 
  group_by(id) |> # group to cumulate within student only
  mutate(
    csum = cumsum(results), # cumulative sum of results
    i = csum - lag(csum, 3, 0) # substract the cumulative sum from 3 observation before. This gives the number of exams passed in the current and previous 2 observations.
    )
```

```r
# Ungroup to get global count
d |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  count(i == 3) # Count the number of cases where the number of exams passes within 3 observations equals 3
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   `i == 3`     n
#>   <lgl>    <int>
#> 1 FALSE       14
#> 2 TRUE         1
```

```r
# Retaining the group gives counts by student
d |>  
  count(i == 3) # Count the number of cases where the number of exams passes within 3 observations equals 3
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>      id `i == 3`     n
#>   <dbl> <lgl>    <int>
#> 1     1 FALSE        6
#> 2     2 FALSE        8
#> 3     2 TRUE         1
```

Since you provided the data as `data.table`, here is how to do the same in that ecosystem:

```r
my_data[ , csum := cumsum(results), .(id)]
my_data[ , i := csum - lag(csum, 3, 0), .(id)]
my_data[ , .(n_cases = sum(i ==3)), id]
#>    id n_cases
#> 1:  1       0
#> 2:  2       1
```